# Does the electron's spin have any impact in a CRT?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electron, crt, spin-of-particles

Fact-1: An electron's (or any-other particle's) magnetic behavior depends upon mass, charge and spin.

Fact-2: All electrons are not the same. Though all electrons have the same mass and charge, an electron can have any 1 of the 2 possible "Spin" (+1/2) and (-1/2) (though later-on the electron can flip to opposite spin state.)

Fact-3: Moving electrons, in a CRT TV, are deflected using magnetic coils.

Are all the electrons coming from the cathode in a CRT TV deflected irrespective of spin (that is, deflection in the CRT does not depend on spin) or does the cathode some-how release all electrons of same spin or does it depend upon spin at all?

Comment: Free electrons can have two spins, and unquantized (continuous) kinetic energy, with infinity of levels possible. They are the same in that if two electrons have sane spin and energy, they are indistinguishable from each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So there are aspects of your question that are wrong, let's first get that out of the way.

Your "fact 2": Wrong.  All electrons are the same.  A more correct statement is that they are indistinguishable from one another. In fact it is this example behaviour that allow fermi statistics to arise and thus gives us a model that is very powerful and accurate in predicting behaviour of the ensemble of particles. In a Quantum system the various *states* that these fermions can take on are determined by the system, but you can not say *which* electron is actually in a given state.

Another assumption you are making. You are conflating quantum effects to macroscopic effects. In a CRT you're not going to see any quantum effects.  The stream of electrons looks like a current and such currents respond of Magnetic fields.

Spin effects do take place, but it is such a small effect that other effects are much much more dominant.  For example the natural repulsion electrons have for each other is very dominant in determining focus size.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you  add to your answer that to be able to measure the spin of electrons (as a whole, gigantic amount of quantums), you'd need very high precision and very strong magnetic fields – the way hydrogen atoms randomly redistribute after a magnetic field is removed is measured in MRIs by the sheer dampened oscillation in EM fields that results from the "step response" of these microscopic systems to change of the magnetic field.

Comment: Ok that means negligible effect. However, within a short time-range, a (+1/2)-spinning-electron, and a (-1/2)-spinning electron are different. isnt?

Answer (score 3):

In principle I think you could sort electrons by their spins.  It's a twist on the [Stern-Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) with electrons.  You need not a magnetic field, but a magnetic field gradient.  You can goolge Stern-Gerlach with electrons and see more.

Comment: Thanks for the statement " you need not a magnetic field, but a magnetic field **gradient** " ... this is a helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

No, the magnetic deflection force on a moving charged particle depends on electron *charge* and *velocity*, and the electric and magnetic field strength; but does not depend on electron *spin*. See Lorentz Force on a Moving Charge in a Combined Electric and Magnetic Field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force